# amazon ec2 and route 53 linking issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am having issues trying to link a domain name that I purchase on amazon route 53 and an EC2 instance that is currently running.

My EC2 has an elastic Ip of 54.66......

and it has a public DNS that looks like ec2-54-66-...-....ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com

if I open in my browser either the IP or the Public DNS I can see the website running

Now, on my route 53 I have purchase/registered a domain, my dashboard displays that I have 1 hosted zone and 1 domain 
that hosted zone has 3 record set count, that looks like this:

[image]

I dont know what I am missing in order to get my domain working (loading my ec2 instance) I have done this several days ago (more than a week, as other domain providers takes up to 48hours to update the dns)

EDIT

I have followed the instruction given by amazon,
[AMAZON INSTRUCTIONS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewDNS.html)

[image: New set up of nameservers]

Comment: Assuming you have the correct nameservers, your domain is not returning a result for a lookup.

Comment: Can you please be more clear with your domain is not returning a result for a lookup?, in regards of the nameservers, is there a way to check that they are right? as I mentioned in the question I have purchased the domain thorugh Route 53

Comment: If you have access to a linux style terminal (OSX terminal works too) you can use two tools to check if the resulting configuration is correct. `whois` will look up the domain name and return the configured nameservers. `dig` will do a DNS lookup to the domain that you specify.

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit confused (this is the first time i use route 53)
when I purchase a domain lets say godaddy, i update their nameservers to what ever nameservers my host providers have. In this case my host provider is EC2, from what I have found online instead of using names servers i have an elastic ip. so do i need to find out nameservers from my ec2 instance? sorry i just dont get it why is not working

Comment: It doesn't matter who you register your domain with. What matters is that the nameservers configured for your domain point to the nameservers provided to you by Route53. Every domain recordset has its own nameservers. Using whois, you can see what nameservers are configured with the domain and check to see if they are the correct ones.

Comment: "www.yoursite.com" is different from "yoursite.com". If just "yoursite.com" is entered in chrome it adds "www." automatically. First try to open just "yoursite.com" by removing www. in firefox or IE. Tell me if that worked or not.

Comment: Hi well, whois was displaying different nameservers as the one that I had in my route53 console, so i modified my console to have the same as whois.
Currently I have this in me route 53 (last image on my original question)